# How to open a Modal dialog instead when submitting data to a php script?

Tags: php, html

I was hoping someone could help. My issue is that currently i have a contact us page that i have set up so that when it is submitted it is posted to a separate php script and that script sends me an email and also shows a blank page with an echo message printed out advising the email has been sent.

What im trying to do is instead of the redirect to a blank page to instead open a modal window to say "thanks for the email" or something similar while the script does its work in the background.

any help would be greatly appreciated, i have searched online for an answer or code examples but have so far failed to find something to match what im trying to do. I have included the relevant parts of the code HTML and PHP that is working in its current iteration. Thanks.

PHP

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = "contactus@example.com";
    $subject = "Contact us message from website";
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
    $subject_option = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Subject: 
    $subject_option\n Message:\n $message";

    echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    } else {
    echo "Failed!";
    }
    ?>
```

HTML

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="panel panel-primary" style="margin:20px;">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3>Feel free to contact us below</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <form method="post" action="../php/mailerscript.php">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name">
                                            Name</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                                            </span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required="required" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
                                            </span>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" required="required" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                                        <select id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                                            <option value="na" selected="">Choose One:</option>
                                            <option value="General Message">General Message</option>
                                            <option value="Suggestions">Suggestions</option>
                                            <option value="Bug Report">Bug Report</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>                                      
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="name">Message</label>
                                        <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="8" cols="40" required="required"
                                            placeholder="Message">
                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="btnContactUs">Send Message</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2"></div>
```

And this is the modal dialog i am trying to trigger (i can trigger it via a separate button so i know that is working), once i get it working i will customize my own but i wanted a proof of concept first.

```
    <!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="thankyouModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-confirm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="icon-box">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE876;</i>
                </div>              
                <h4 class="modal-title">Awesome!</h4>   
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="text-center">Your booking has been confirmed. Check your email for detials.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:- I can see this has been marked as an exact match to an existing question, it is different in my opinion as looking at both questions my issue is submitting a contact us html form and then showing a modal box instead of a redirect whereas the other is something to do with passing information from a modal box which i,m not interested in doing.

I've probably not explained myself very well (i'll never make it as a teacher) :-) and thats why its been marked as a duplicate but if its to do with needing AJAX then i'll look into that as I've never had to use it and hadn't considered it until now, i thought i could do it with just HTML and PHP. :-)

Comment: You should Use Ajax.on submit call PHP page and show thankyou modal.

Comment: Thanks @TarangP I'll give that a go. I hadn't considered needing Ajax, I've not had to use Ajax before so didnt consider it, i thought i could just do it with plain old HTML and PHP! haha more fool me. thanks